# Compile results from facial expression recognition real time

Tags: python

I am running facial expression recognition which gives predicted expression real time. Currently it will show the facial expression identified from the video.

This code is under a For loop.

```
  predictions = model.predict(img_pixls) 

 #index array 0: angry, 1:disgust, 2:fear, 3:happy, 4:sad, 5:surprise, 6:neutral

  index = np.argmax(predictions[0])

Based on the returns I will be getting the index as it predicts each facial expression.
```

How can I allow the system to run let say a period of time and group the count the occurrences of readings based on positive and negative? I would like to group 0, 1, 2, 4 as negative and 3,5,6 as positive. If the real time reading is (4,4,3,1,0,3,3,6,6,6) I would like the system to return results based on whether the reading is more positive or negative after pressing enter key to pause the For loop and continue reading when enter key is pressed again.

```
4 (2), 
3 (3)
1 (1)
0 (1)
6 (3)
Positive (6) Negative (4)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

pos_list = [3, 5, 6]
neg_list = [0,1,2,4]

Then:
overall_score = 0 
if index in pos_list:
score +=1 
if index in neg_list:
score -=1

then loop through all the indexes that have returned

return score will give you a positive, a zero or a negative value in the end.